# Direct nuclear reaction in nuclear physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

Time taken to occur a direct nuclear reaction is very low $10^{-22}$sec . I want to know the Importance of direct nuclear reactions.

Comment: Same comment I made on your [subsequent question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45080/520).

Comment: -1. No reaearch effort.

Answer (score 1):

from  the wiki article on [nuclear reactions:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_reaction)

> **Direct reactions**
>
> An intermediate energy projectile transfers energy or picks up or loses nucleons to the nucleus in a single quick (10−21 second) event. Energy and momentum transfer are relatively small. These are particularly useful in experimental nuclear physics, because the reaction mechanisms are often simple enough to calculate with sufficient accuracy to probe the structure of the target nucleus.

So their importance lies in their use as a probe to study a nucleus, i.e determine its energy levels, quadrupole moment etc. The short lifetime is indicative of a strong interaction lifetime ( in contrast to weak decays or electromagnetic interactions which are much slower)